# A combinatoric generalization of Zeta

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Recall the well known identity

$\zeta(s)=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}, Re(s)>1$

Now take a infinite discrete sequence of real values $r_k$ such that $r_1<r_2<...<r_k$ and denote $A$ the set of all possible combination (in the sense of all the result of all possible product, including $r_k*1$, just like the integer are product of primes) of the $r_k$. Let's denote by $A(n)$ the $n$-th element of $A$, ordered the same way as the $r_k$.

Now we can construct the relation

$f(s):=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-r_k^{-s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{A(n)^s}, Re(s)>c$

Which would hold for any "good" sequence of $r_k$ and would suggest that RH is more a statement about the relationship between additive and multiplicative properties for a set of number than a statement about the prime only (if it means something...).

Then, we might be able to write that

$1/f(s)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} {(1-r_k^{-s})}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(A(n))}{A(n)^s}, Re(s)>c$

Here $\mu(A(n))$ is define like $\mu(n)$ but the primes are exchange with the $r_k$. This identity leads to a relationship between the location of the zeros of $f$ and the behavior of the sequence $(r_k)$.

Since you can define this relation for any (well chosen ?) sequence of $r_k$ the Dirichlet $L$-function are just a special case of this general property. We then might be able to study the $r_k$ in order to understand the properties that would lead $f$ to satisfy a RH. Maybe all functions $f$ (associated to a well chosen sequence of $r_k$) have their zeros on a line and are symmetric in respect to this line. It is of course pure speculation but in favor of this idea, there is a fact that the Davenport $\zeta$ function, which satisfy some of the same properties as the $\zeta$ function but doesn't have an Euler product representation, has zeros off the critical line.

Note that the $\zeta$ function is a very special case since you have

$A(n+1)=A(n)+1$ which hold if and only if the sequence $({r_n})$ is the sequence of prime. It is the same fact that makes $\zeta$ the "easiest" $L$-function to study. Note that all Dirichlet $L$-function show those kind of periodicity because of the caracter $\chi$

It is unclear to me what kind of "good" properties you should gives to the $(r_k)$ in order to satisfy a RH.

And since the $A(n)$ are the product of the $r_k$ and that all such product are unique, under RH there would be reason for $\sum_{A(n)<=x}{\mu(A(n))}$ to be $O(x^{1/2}log(x))$, since the $r_k$ combine in $A$ the same way that primes combine in the set of integers. Which suggest that showing RH for a sequence of $r_k$ is enough to show that all function $f$ would satisfy a RH.

We might be able to this for function. Calling $r_k(x)$ a sequence of real function that satisfy $r_1(x)<r_2(x)<...<r_k(x)$ (1) for all $x$ in some domain and calling $G_n(x)$ the set of all values of the product between the  $r_k(x)$. Condition (1) guaranty that we can order $G_n(x)$ in the same way as we ordered the $A(n)$. So we will have the relation

$f(s,x):=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-r_k(x)^{-s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{G_n(x)^s}, Re(s)>c$

**Q :** Is such generalization possible ? Is there any available study of such generalization of the Euler product ?

Comment: should look into the concept of Beurling generalized primes; there is a book by Diamond and Zhang which gives a good discussion; the paper by Zhang  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-006-0051-5 shows that things are tricky as RH goes

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help